# How does this meta-programming compile down?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Here's an example from wikipedia that displays C++ template meta-programming:

```
template <int N>
struct Factorial 
{
    enum { value = N * Factorial<N - 1>::value };
};

template <>
struct Factorial<0> 
{
    enum { value = 1 };
};

// Factorial<4>::value == 24
// Factorial<0>::value == 1
void foo()
{
    int x = Factorial<4>::value; // == 24
    int y = Factorial<0>::value; // == 1
}
```

I understand how it works, recursively creating types of Factorial with template parameter values for N until the specialization is found <0>, which allows the compiler to resolve the values up the chain.

My question is: how would this look after compilation? Will the compiler literally end up just generating something like:

```
int x = 24;
int y = 1;
```

or will the result be more complex?  I'm asking because I'm wondering if it basically results in:

```
Factorial<4>::value
```

being replaced by a constant (24) in the executable code or if its more complex than that.  I'm just trying to figure out how this helps efficiency in the completed program, so this would help a lot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, here's the generated assembly from GCC:

```
 ; command line used: gcc -c -S -fmasm-intel test.cpp

    .file   "test.cpp"
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .text
.globl __Z3foov
    .def    __Z3foov;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
__Z3foov:
LFB0:
    push    ebp
LCFI0:
    mov ebp, esp
LCFI1:
    sub esp, 16
LCFI2:
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-4], 24
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-8], 1
    leave
LCFI3:
    ret
LFE0:
```

And MSVC:

```
; command line used: cl -c /FAsc test.cpp

; Listing generated by Microsoft (R) Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.30319.01 

; removed soem excessive noise...

?foo@@YAXXZ PROC                    ; foo

; 16   : {

  00000 55       push    ebp
  00001 8b ec        mov     ebp, esp
  00003 83 ec 08     sub     esp, 8

; 17   :     int x = Factorial<4>::value; // == 24

  00006 c7 45 f8 18 00
    00 00        mov     DWORD PTR _x$[ebp], 24 ; 00000018H

; 18   :     int y = Factorial<0>::value; // == 1

  0000d c7 45 fc 01 00
    00 00        mov     DWORD PTR _y$[ebp], 1

; 19   : }

  00014 8b e5        mov     esp, ebp
  00016 5d       pop     ebp
  00017 c3       ret     0
?foo@@YAXXZ ENDP                    ; foo
_TEXT   ENDS
END
```

So the answer is that they boil the meta-programming down to its final result.

Note that I didn't even use any optimization flags.

Comment: I'd say that generated assembly in this case (or even in all cases) mostly demonstrates the optimization capabilities of the specific compiler. And I don't see the OP mention GCC.

Comment: @AndreyT: I understand that 'proof by compiler' isn't much of a proof, but the OP asked "My question is: how would this look after compilation?". However, I agree that your answer is much more important to showing that it's a requirement of the language, rather than an implementation detail.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, they are reduced to immediate compile-time values. A more telling example would be something like

```
int a[Factorial<4>::value];
```

or

```
struct S {
  int a : Factorial<4>::value;
};
```

or

```
switch (a) {
  case Factorial<4>::value: ;
}
```

i.e. contexts where constant compile-time values are required by the language. None of these examples would compile if `Factorial<4>::value` wasn't an immediate compile-time constant.

Comment: wait, what's that second one?

Comment: @Michael Burr: facepalm! I've done more bitfields than most people I know, but always used literals.  I should have recognized that.

Comment: @Mooing: well, now this will come immediately to mind next time you need a factorial-sized bitfield. I had a need for this just the other day.

Answer (score 3):

> Will the compiler literally end up just generating something like:

Yes. That's the whole point of doing something like that this way.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is: how would this look after compilation? Will the compiler literally end up just generating something like:

Yes. `Factorial<3>::value` is actually a constant expression. That means, you can even write these:

```
const int M = Factorial<Factorial<3>::value>::value;
const int N = Factorial<Factorial<Factorial<3>::value>::value>::value;
```

And these too:

```
int array[Factorial<5>::value]; //its NOT a variable length array (VLA)
std::bitset<Factorial<5>::value> bits;
```

That is, wherever compile-time constant is required, you can use `Factorial<5>::value`.

Answer (score 0):

They are indeed compiled down to the former,

```
int x = 24;
int y = 1;
```

Though you'll find it difficult to come up with a real use for this pattern in actual production programs...

Comment: Nothing in Boost uses this kind of recursive pre-processing to replace a normal function call with a compile-time constant. They only use it to create tail-recursive lists.

Comment: FYI, The [Boost.Integer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/integer/doc/static_log2.html) library provides a recursive definition for static_log2, which is used in the Hash and Interprocess libraries.

Comment: I frequently used it to calculate the number of bits in each type.